# Checkbox change is being detected twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to use a `checkbox` to show if a service is running when it's checked, and uncked if is not running, this is my checkbox.

```
<input id="controller" type="checkbox" class="switch-small" checked > Controller
```

[image]

Then I'm using this `JavaScript` to capture the event.

In the code below I would like to know if the service is running or not, so I could change its state properly, for example, if is checked, and the user clicked on it, he would like to stop the service, and vice-versa.

```
var state = false;
if ( $('#controller').prop('checked') ){
  state = true;
}
```

But something is wrong in my code below, because the `change` is called twice and I don't know why is that, I would like to be called just once.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#controller').change(function () {

        if (!state){
            alert("ON");
        } else {
            alert("OFF");
        }

        if ( $('#controller').prop('checked') ){
            state = true;
        }else{
            state = false;
        }

    });
});
```

All my component has unique ID's. 
Any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything immediately wrong with your code. Can you create a fiddle (or built-in SO example)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted here, is it possible to get a fiddle from you so we can check further?

Comment: Your code seems to work ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0spgbbp/1/)). Note it can be simplified ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0spgbbp/)).

Comment: maybe your event is bubbling?

Comment: @j08691,@artm,@Oriol,@ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, thank you so much for your tips. It really seems to be working correctly my code then. I didn't know how to use fiddle, thank you very much for the intro.

Comment: My problem it seems to be the amount of `js` files that's been use in this page. I removed some of them and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var state;
$('#controller').click( function () {
    state = this.checked;
    alert(state ? "ON" : "OFF");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input id="controller" type="checkbox" class="switch-small" checked="checked" />
    Controller
</label>
```